# How to convert a multiline textarea input array format data in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

Here is a textarea where I want to enter multiple line input [Textarea input field in Vue js with multiple lines input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCaqq.png)

And I wanted to convert the input data into an array format data like ['Value 1','Value 2', ...] in Vue.js. Thank you.

Comment: what have tried so far, please share the code

Answer (score 1):

You could create a computed property that returns the textarea content splitted by `\n` which represents the new line character:

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
   content:''
    }
  },
  computed:{
     contentArr(){
       return this.content.split('\n')
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <textarea v-model="content">
  </textarea>
  <ul>
  <li v-for="item in contentArr">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```